# adding minimum and maximum value in JavaScript event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I was wondering if anyone could help me out, the purpose of the code below is to translate the whole screen left every time the user clicks a button, so

> page one = var distance = 0
>
> page one = var distance = -100
>
> page one = var distance = -200

and so on but I don't want the user going way of the amount of pages which have a width of 100%, is there some way to put boundary's on this so minimum = 0 and maximum = 500

```
var distance = 0;
    $('.right').click(function() {
        distance -= 100;
        $('#container').css('transform', 'translateX(' + distance + '%)')
        console.log(distance);
    });
    $('.left').click(function() {
        distance += 100;
        $('#container').css('transform', 'translateX(' + distance + '%);')
        console.log(distance);
    });
```

Comment: You can put a IF Condition of distance variable

Answer (score 2):

**[`Math.min()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min)** and **[`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)** will do the trick

```
var distance = 0;

$('.right').click(function() {
    distance = Math.max(0, distance- 100);
    $('#container').css('transform', 'translateX(' + distance + '%)')
    console.log(distance);
});
$('.left').click(function() {
    distance = Math.min(500, distance+ 100);
    $('#container').css('transform', 'translateX(' + distance + '%);')
    console.log(distance);
});
```

---

Or you can use ternary operator

```
var distance = 0;

$('.right').click(function() {
    distance -=  (distance==0 ? 0 : 100);
    $('#container').css('transform', 'translateX(' + distance + '%)')
    console.log(distance);
});
$('.left').click(function() {
    distance += (distance==500 ? 0 : 100);
    $('#container').css('transform', 'translateX(' + distance + '%);')
    console.log(distance);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

So add if statements and check if the number is less than zero when you are decreasing the number

```
if (distance<0) distance = 0;
```

and when you are incrementing, see if it is above your max.

```
if (distance>500) distance = 500;
```